# Reposition an element to the front of an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Even coming from javascript this looks atrocious to me:

```
irb
>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
=> ["a", "b", "c"]
>> a.unshift(a.delete('c'))
=> ["c", "a", "b"]
```

Is there a more legible way placing an element to the front of an array?

**Edit** my actual code:

```
if @admin_users.include?(current_user)
  @admin_users.unshift(@admin_users.delete(current_user))
end
```

Comment: the question is not clear, you ask for a more readable way of "placing an element to the front of an array" (`Array#insert(index, value)`?) but the example uses `delete` and seems like you wanted a rotation.

Comment: ok, now it's clear. Has it to be in-place update, though? why not return a new array?

Comment: `unshift` is a pretty opaque name. Does it become more legible to you if you just alias it as `prepend`?

Comment: @pje `unshift` is clear enough, but you must know that `delete` returns the deleted element to understand what's happening. In the end I settled for `array.sort_by{|element| element == "c" ? 0 : 1}`

Comment: Note that this could shrink the array, as it will delete all occurrences of `current_user`, but only add one to the front.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a trickier problem than it seems. I defined the following tests:

```
describe Array do
  describe '.promote' do
    subject(:array) { [1, 2, 3] }

    it { expect(array.promote(2)).to eq [2, 1, 3] }
    it { expect(array.promote(3)).to eq [3, 1, 2] }
    it { expect(array.promote(4)).to eq [1, 2, 3] }
    it { expect((array + array).promote(2)).to eq [2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3] }
  end
end
```

`sort_by` proposed by @Duopixel is elegant but produces `[3, 2, 1]` for the second test.

```
class Array
  def promote(promoted_element)
    sort_by { |element| element == promoted_element ? 0 : 1 }
  end
end
```

@tadman uses `delete`, but this deletes all matching elements, so the output of the fourth test is `[2, 1, 3, 1, 3]`.

```
class Array
  def promote(promoted_element)
    if (found = delete(promoted_element))
      unshift(found)
    end

    self
  end
end
```

I tried using:

```
class Array
  def promote(promoted_element)
    return self unless (found = delete_at(find_index(promoted_element)))
    unshift(found)
  end
end
```

But that failed the third test because `delete_at` can't handle nil. Finally, I settled on:

```
class Array
  def promote(promoted_element)
    return self unless (found_index = find_index(promoted_element))
    unshift(delete_at(found_index))
  end
end
```

Who knew a simple idea like `promote` could be so tricky?

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't believe how far down the rabbit hole such a simple seeming method took me.

Comment: This is good.  Just an observation: your chosen `promote` presupposes that it is only supposed to move the first occurrence of `promoted_element`.  `Array#delete` removes all elements matching the parameter.  Would it be unreasonable to expect orthogonal behavior from`promote` and that the result of your fourth test would be `[2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3]`? To use your `promote` as a component in a method that moves all occurrences of `promoted_element` would require repeatedly duplicating the array and comparing (I think...).

Comment: @Huliax What was nice about adding tests is that it makes by desired approach with promote completely explicit. If instead you want to "percolate" all of a certain element to the front, try something like: `[1,2,3,1,2,3].sort_by { |e| e == 2 ? -1 : 0 }`. [Rewrote to fix bug.]

Comment: Tests are great! Just as you say, my group often relies on them as part of our documentation. That said, it is really nice when you don't have to look at the tests to understand the behavior of a method.  It is the pinnacle of self documentation when a method does just what you think it will when all you know its signature.  Part of that is knowing how 'sibling' methods work (e.g. `#delete`). There is value in consistency. To me, that is one of the nice things about Ruby, that things do what you expect them to. Well, until they don't...Ruby has its fair share of that lurking in the corners...

Answer (score 25):

Maybe this looks better to you:

```
a.insert(0, a.delete('c'))
```

Comment: This is a great solution when the source array is guaranteed to be unique.  The accepted answer above covers more scenarios; however, if the array won't contain duplicates this is quicker and easier to implement than the above - IMHO of course.

Answer (score 20):

Maybe [Array#rotate](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-rotate) would work for you:

```
['a', 'b', 'c'].rotate(-1)
#=> ["c", "a", "b"]
```

Comment: Good to know. Unfortunately it's not a matter of putting the last element(s) to the front, it's taking an arbitrary element and putting it to the front. I've updated my question and apologies.

Comment: I didn't know that method.

Comment: The question came up first on google for: "ruby move one array element to the front". My poor googling came up with the correct answer in the end. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 6):

Adding my two cents:

```
array.select{ |item| <condition> } | array
```

Pros:

- Can move multiple items to front of array

Cons:

- This will remove all duplicates unless it's the desired outcome.

Example - Move all ***odd*** numbers to the front (and make array unique):

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 1]
data.select{ |item| item.odd? } | data
# Short version:
data.select(&:odd?) | data
```

Result:

```
[1, 3, 5, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 6):

Another way:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = 3

[b] + (a - [b])
=> [3, 1, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 5):

If by "elegant" you mean more readable even at the expense of being non-standard, you could always write your own method that enhances Array:

```
class Array
  def promote(value)
    if (found = delete(value))
      unshift(found)
    end

    self
  end
end

a = %w[ a b c ]
a.promote('c')
# => ["c", "a", "b"] 
a.promote('x')
# => ["c", "a", "b"]
```

Keep in mind this would only reposition a single instance of a value. If there are several in the array, subsequent ones would probably not be moved until the first is removed.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the etiquette of extending native classes in Ruby. Would this be considered bad form as it is in javascript?

Comment: Ruby on Rails has an enormous number of extensions to the Ruby core classes, so it's become a sort of tradition. It really depends. There's a fine line between clever and *too* clever. If you perform this operation in a lot of places, it would make sense. If in just one, I'd stick with what you have.

Answer (score 4):

In the end I considered this the most readable alternative to moving an element to the front:

```
if @admin_users.include?(current_user)
  @admin_users.sort_by{|admin| admin == current_user ? 0 : 1}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the elements in the array are unique you can use array arithmetic:

```
> a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
=> ["a", "b", "c"]
> a -= "c"
=> ["a", "b"]
> a = ["c"] + a
=> ["c", "a", "b"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on above:

```
class Array
  def promote(*promoted)
    self - (tail = self - promoted) + tail
  end
end

[1,2,3,4].promote(5)
=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
[1,2,3,4].promote(4)
=> [4, 1, 2, 3]
[1,2,3,4].promote(2,4)
=> [2, 4, 1, 3]
```